# Calculate risk ratio after balancing with WeightIt

Tags: r, dataframe, weighted, propensity-score-matching

I used `WeightIt` to balance the characteristics of my population dividing into treated and non-treated as in this example:

```
library(cobalt)
library(WeightIt)
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")
head(lalonde)

W.out <- weightit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75,
                  data = lalonde, estimand = "ATT", method = "ps")
```

My outcome is `re78`. I would like to calculate the **RISK RATIO** with 95% CONFIDENCE INTERVALS.
How can I do it?
For odds ratio I know that I can use the `survey` package and the `svyglm` function as in this example:

```
library(survey)
d.w <- svydesign(~1, weights = W.out$weights, data = lalonde)
fit <- svyglm(re78 ~ treat, design = d.w)
coef(fit)
```

but how can I compute risk ratios with their 95% CI instead of odds ratio in my weighted dataset?

Comment: If you do Poisson regression instead of logistic regression you can easily get risk ratios.

Comment: @IRTFM could you please help me with writing the code?

Comment: I tried to use your code to prepare a weighting scheme but get this with the code you used to produce W.out: `Error: 'method' must be a string of length 1 containing the name of an acceptable weighting method or a function that produces weights.`

Comment: @IRTFM I am sorry, you are right. I corrected the post. Instead of method="glm" it is method="ps"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `re78` is not integer you need to use `quasipoisson` instead of `poisson` if you want to avoid warnings, although the software gives the dame results.

```
 fit <- svyglm(re78 ~ treat, design = d.w, family="quasipoisson")

coef(fit)
(Intercept)       treat 
   8.543849    0.212226 

coef(summary(fit))
            Estimate Std. Error   t value      Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 8.543849  0.1146916 74.494128 4.321164e-309
treat       0.212226  0.1463640  1.449987  1.475743e-01
```

The risk ratio is just `exp(coef(fit)[2])` and it's CI is just this pseudo code.

```
exp( coef(fit)[2] +/- 1.96*coef( summary(fit))[2,2] )
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You have been really helpful.